# Ubuntu 14.04 with Parallels on Mac

Tags: 14.04, mac, virtualization, tools, parallels

last week I´ve tried to install Ubuntu 14.04 with Parallels as a Vm it works well but I
didnt could install the Parallels Tool.
For test I have tried 12.04 too and the Parallels Tools are working perfectly.

Someone have experience with that?
Would be nice to have some information how I can install the Tools on 14.04.

Greetings